# View and add contact in created application

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am creating an Android application which requires to view contacts from phone's contact and add contacts or sync it into my application. Is it possible to do this? How?

Thanks..

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "add it to my application".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely possible use content resolver and cursor

e.g. Reading contacts names

```
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().
    query( Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
      new String[]{Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null,null);

    if(cursor!=null){
      while(cursor.moveToNext()){

         String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME))
       }
```

Use following link for more information

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html